# Python Black package is not working when "black filename.py" is used in conda envvironment

Tags: python, package, conda, virtual-environment, python-black

I need to use python `black` (the code formatter), but seeing this issue

- for that I first moved to the git branch where I need to update environment with black package
- then activate the environment with `conda activate my_env`
- then I installed black using `conda install -c conda-forge black`
- then I checked if black was installed using `conda list -n my_env black` (it was present in list)
- then I used black to format a file with command `black file_name.py`

I am seeing this issue: https://www.screencast.com/t/8PzgwTMt

Unable to create process using `<path>/python.exe <path>/black-script.py filename.py`

Comment: Try `python -m black file_name.py`. Same/no/different error?

Comment: ..../../python.exe No module name black error appears

Comment: This points towards `black` not being installed. I'm unfamiliar with condo and can't help you there. I usually use pip.

Comment: SOLUTION: I had 2 similar environment variables C:\Users\Username\Anaconda3;C:\Users\Username\Anaconda3\Scripts; I uninstalled conda which removed these 2 variables, reinstalled with path addition selected (which mean only the latter path was added in environment variables itself) , then in the envrionment I installed Black using pip, works correctly now

Comment: Just had this same issue and @TinNguyen's comment solved it